# How to use MOD in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In MySQL, I can do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE MOD(attr, 2) = 0;
```

it gives me all rows which `attr` is even.

How can I do it in Sequelize? I didn't find in the docs.

Something like:

```js
MyModel.findAll({
  where: {
    attr: {
        [Op.mod]: [2, 0]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `literal` (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/sub-queries/) if you need full flexibility:

```js
MyModel.findAll({
  where: sequelize.literal('MOD(attr, 2) = 0')
})
```

Otherwise you can just call the desired function using `fn` (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#advanced-queries-with-functions-not-just-columns):

```js
MyModel.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('MOD', sequelize.col('attr')), 0)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not [`sequelize.fn()`](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#static-method-fn)? [The "core concepts" docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#advanced-queries-with-functions-not-just-columns) illustrate almost exactly what you're trying to do:

```
MyModel.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('MOD', sequelize.col('attr')), 0)
});
```